# Fourier series expansion

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Is it possible to have a Fourier sine series expansion like
$$
\sin\left(\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi\right)x\right)
$$ instead of the normal $$\sin(n \pi x)$$

Comment: Do your basis functions satisfy the periodicity conditions?

Comment: Yes on $[-1,1]$

Comment: No. The basis is anti-periodic: $\sin\left((\frac\pi2 + n \pi)(x+2)\right)=-\sin\left((\frac\pi2 + n \pi)x\right)$. So if you are considering anti-periodic functions, these would be fine but not for periodic functions for which the standard Fourier series is applied.

Comment: Is there any way to write a series expansion in terms of the above expression?

Comment: Like, if the function were anti-periodic?

Comment: Just kidding, seems to work the same as normal Fourier

Answer (score 3):

Not only possible, but sometimes necessary. This is the expansion one uses to deal with the mixed boundary value problem on $[0,1]$: 
$$u(0,t)=0,\quad u_x(1,t)=0 \tag{1}$$
The sine functions you listed satisfy these boundary conditions. Subject to (1) and some initial condition, the wave and diffusion equations will have solutions in the form 
$$
u(x,t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sin\left(\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + n\pi\right)x\right) T_n(t)
$$
The factors $T_n(t)$ are determined by the PDE and the initial condition.